# Can start win phone 8 emulator from hyper-v manager but not from vs2013

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

Hello I'm able to launch the windows phone emulator from the hyper-v manager but not from visual studio 2013, I retrive the following error message:

windows phone emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here are some steps to do it.

1. Open Hyper-v Manager From Apps
2. After Opening Hyper-v Manager, Select Your PC name from list given in left most first tab.
3. Now you are able to see all Emulator images list
4. Right click on the emulator you want to run and select Start option.

for Reference here are images :

[image: Hyper-v Manager]
[image: Windows Phone Emulator]

Comment: yes, but my problem is that I can't run the emulator from visual studio.

Comment: Don't you find the emulator option from your VS Editor? You're sure na that you installed the VS without any issues?